# EmguCV cascade classifier slow at first, then fast

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, face-detection

I am using EmguCV's CascadeClassifier to detect faces in an image using DetectMultiScale, and while detecting the first image takes a while (around 3-5 seconds), the subsequent images only take about 0.3-0.7 seconds. I initialized the classifier on load to see if that changed anything but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Is there any way I could speed up the time of the the first image?

Comment: if you are running this project from visual studio solution ,it will be like that.But you run it from exe(i.e in actual use of project) , you may not get this problem.try that.

Comment: Nope, even running the binaries is slow at first, then fast.

Comment: if you running cascadeclassifier on gpu, then it may be the cuda which is initialing  that slowly for the first time but not actual opencv algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I think it´s the dynamical assembly loading. .Net only loads the needed EmguCV assembly if needed. So first time you use any EmguCV Code it loads the whole assembly. This may take a while. 
You could initialize the assembly using emguCV right after program start in a seperate thread. While Loading you could do other init stuff.

Maybe there is also an option on references to load the assembly right from the start.